# C# Write byte to serial port like failed

Tags: c#, serial-port

Why the byte output from another program is like nothing happening when I use it on own program? The data is from sample program:-

[image]

When I use the `A5 00 01 02 13 02 01 55` in my program, nothing happen while the sample program can trigger the light on device.

My code:-

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using ComTypes = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;
using COMLib;
using System.Linq;

namespace PortLPT
{
    class Program
    {
        static SerialPort twrport = new SerialPort();
        static string InputData = String.Empty;
        static string comname;
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            COMLibrary comport = new COMLibrary();
            var comdevice = comport.GetAllCOMPorts();
            foreach(var devinfo in comdevice)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Port Number: {devinfo.name}.\nPort Description: {devinfo.decsription}.\n{new string('=',"Port Description".Length + devinfo.decsription.Length + 3)}");
                if (devinfo.decsription.Contains("MOXA"))
                    comname = devinfo.name;
            }

            twrport.PortName = comname;
            twrport.BaudRate = 9600;
            twrport.DataBits = 8;
            twrport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            twrport.Parity = Parity.None;
            twrport.Open();
            twrport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
            twrport.RtsEnable = true;
            twrport.DtrEnable = true;   


            if (!(twrport.IsOpen))
            {
                try
                {
                    twrport.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Serial port connection successfully open.");
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Exception on opening serial port connection. Ex-{ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Serial port connection successfully open.");
            }

            try
            {
                string str = "A5 00 01 02 13 02 01 55";
                byte[] bytes = str.Split(' ').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[8] { 0xA5, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x13, 0x02, 0x01, 0x55 };
                if (!(twrport.IsOpen))
                    twrport.Open();
                twrport.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                twrport.Close();
                Console.WriteLine($"Write to port: {PrintBytes(bytes)}");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            { Console.WriteLine($"Error write to port. Ex-{ex.Message.ToString()}"); twrport.Close(); }
            


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
            Console.WriteLine(twrport.ReadExisting());
        }
        static string PrintBytes(byte[] byteArray)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder("{");
            for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
            {
                var b = byteArray[i];
                sb.Append(b);
                if (i < byteArray.Length - 1)
                {
                    sb.Append(", ");
                }
            }
            sb.Append("}");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I have try two kind of byte style which is variable `bytes[]` and `buffer[]`. Both not success. How do I make this write to serial port accordingly?

I'm not so expert on this. I have try some ade write to serial port link from search engine result and still failed to trigger the device

## Updated

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't be closing the port immediately after writing to it?

Comment: I already did it before..same thing happen..nothing were trigger on device

Comment: Double check PortName, BaudRate, DataBits, StopBits, Parity. Is all correct?

Comment: I believe all the serial port settings are follow accordingly on what the sample program does.

Comment: What is that sample program you use?

Comment: Its a docklight program from https://docklight.de/download/Docklight.zip

Comment: I would check the value of `SerialPort.BytesToWrite` after `Write` & before `Close`.

Comment: Ok, I will try that on Monday to see the value.